# Directive needs data updated after element is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Having trouble getting a directive to display properly with data that is updated via promise.  The first directive updates perfectly, but the second and third do not.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OmVKH2g3cH3DemvK5Lt?p=preview)

First, the data:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $timeout(function() {
      angular.copy({totalItems: 100, pageSize: 10, currentPage: 1 }, $scope.data);
  }, 3000);
});
```

Then the directives:

```
var template1 = '{{(data.pageSize * (data.currentPage - 1)) + 1}} - {{data.pageSize * data.currentPage}} of {{data.totalItems}}';
var template2 = '{{lower}} - {{upper}} of {{total}}';
var dir = {
  restrict: 'C',
  template: template1,
  scope: false
};

app.directive('pagination', function() {
    return dir;    
});

app.directive('pagination2', function() {
  dir.template = template2;
  dir.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.lower = (attrs.size * (attrs.currentPage - 1)) + 1;
    scope.upper = (attrs.size * attrs.currentPage);
    scope.total = attrs.total;
  };

  return dir;
});

app.directive('pagination3', function() {
  dir.template = template2;
  dir.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.lower = (scope.data.pageSize * (scope.data.currentPage - 1)) + 1;
    scope.upper = (scope.data.pageSize * scope.data.currentPage);
    scope.total = scope.data.totalItems;
  };

  return dir;
});
```

And lastly the markup:

```
<div class="pagination"></div>
<div class="pagination2" total="{{data.totalItems}}" size="{{data.pageSize}}" current-page="{{data.currentPage}}"></div>
<div class="pagination3"></div>
```

I understand why the first one works.  The `$timeout` finishes, my `$scope` is updated, dirty check ensues, everything is recalculated, and all is well.

In the second one I *think* I understand why it doesn't update - because the data is not there when I pass values to the element attributes, meaning the entire directive is built using `undefined` values.  I would like to somehow correct this and have the directive update when `$scope.data` updates.

I figured I'd solve the problem I was having with the second directive with the third directive but am quite confused why this one doesn't work.  I thought I had direct access to the `$scope` because my directive is using `scope: false`, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('pagination3', function() {
  dir.template = template2;
  dir.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.lower = (scope.data.pageSize * (scope.data.currentPage - 1)) + 1;
    scope.upper = (scope.data.pageSize * scope.data.currentPage);
    scope.total = scope.data.totalItems;
};

return dir;
});
```

Per your code, you are assigning `scope.data.totalItems` at directive's linking phase but at that time `scope.data` is just an empty object `{}`, it has no property called `totalItems` or `pageSize` or `currentPage`. lower, upper and total will be `undefined` after the assignment.

If you really don't want to put the calculation in your view template, you can monitor `scope.data`'s change as below

```
app.directive('pagination3', function() {
  dir.template = template2;
  dir.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      scope.lower = (newVal.pageSize * (newVal.currentPage - 1)) + 1;
      scope.upper = (newVal.pageSize * newVal.currentPage);
      scope.total = newVal.totalItems;
    }, true);
  };
  return dir;
};
```

Comment: Ah ya that makes sense.  Though I still don't understand how to get that data into my directive in a way that I can use repeatedly without having to manipulate my `$scope.data` object in the template itself.

Comment: @diplosaurus check my update, it might give you a hint.

Comment: Hmm that's what I was trying with that `console.log` but it never fires.  Almost as if the `$watch` is never set up.

Comment: Did you add a third parameter `true` as I do ? @diplosaurus

Comment: Yep, sadly no effect in either my app or plunkr.

Comment: can you share me link of your plunkr?

Comment: @diplosaurus delete your `pagination2` directive definition or element in the view, then `pagination3` would work as charm.

Comment: Ah pffft, fail.  Thanks much.